# Creating Model using Swifty JSon Model

Tags: json, swift3, swifty-json

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1212323",
        "row": 1,
        "column": 1,
        "displayType": 0,
        "item": {
            "type": "category_",
            "data": {
                "_id": "595a1446cb91951900b0b4b0",
                "title": "something",
                "fullImage": "http://assets.something.mobi/curated/something (2).jpg",
                "halfImage": "http://assets.something.mobi/curated/something (1).jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "595a148ccb91951900b0b4b5",
        "row": 2,
        "column": 1,
        "displayType": 1,
        "item": {
            "type": "curatedlist",
            "data": {
                "_id": "595b34abcb9195190c0ae378",
                "active": "true",
                "title": "sample something list",
                "fullImage": "http://assets.something.mobi/curated/something (2).jpg",
                "halfImage": "http://assets.something.mobi/curated/something (2).jpg"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

very new to SwiftyJSON and Alamofire some one please help me to create a model for it im able get JSON responce using almofire but not able to create a proper swifty json model for this

Comment: Since you are using Alamofire, why don't you use [`AlamofireObjectMapper`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) over `SwifyJSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using two separate model classes, one to directly map all the values and other used to fetch directly as an array from it.

For some who just starting or stuck with creating model and mapping values can try these or someone is an expert can suggest a better solution to improve the implementation

1.CategoryModel: NSObject

```
    import UIKit
    import SwiftyJSON

    class CategoryModel: NSObject {
        var resultArray : NSArray!
        var _id : String!
        var row : NSInteger!
        var column : NSInteger!
        var displayType : NSInteger!

        var type : String?

        var _id1 : String?
        var title : String?
        var fullImage : String?
        var halfImage : String?
        // var item


        required init(JsonDashBoard: JSON) {

            _id = JsonDashBoard["_id"].stringValue
            row = JsonDashBoard["row"].intValue
            column = JsonDashBoard["column"].intValue
            displayType = JsonDashBoard["displayType"].intValue

            //MARK:- Inside Item Dictionary
            type = JsonDashBoard["item"]["type"].stringValue
            //MARK:- Inside Item/dataDictionary
            _id1 = JsonDashBoard["item"]["data"]["_id"].stringValue
            title = JsonDashBoard["item"]["data"]["title"].stringValue
            fullImage = JsonDashBoard["item"]["data"]["fullWidthImage"].stringValue
            halfImage = JsonDashBoard["item"]["data"]["halfWidthImage"].stringValue

        }
    }
```

2.CategoryListModel:NSObject

```
  import UIKit

    class CategoryListModel: NSObject {
        var items : NSArray? = nil;
        required init(_items: NSMutableArray) {
            self.items = _items
        }
    }
```

and using these model classes you can map values using the below code snipet

```
manager.request(routeUrl, method: .get).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            let categoryList = NSMutableArray()
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in resJson {

                let model = CategoryModel(JsonDashBoard: subJson)
                categoryList.add(model)
                //Do something you want
                print(subJson)

            }
            let categoryListModel = CategoryListModel(_items: categoryList)
            success(categoryListModel)


        }
        if responseObject.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
            failure(error)
        }


    }
```